# How do I list all the entries in LDAP directory information tree?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm running OpenLDAP 2.4.42, and this is my configuration file:

```
include C:/OpenLDAP/schema/core.schema
include C:/OpenLDAP/schema/cosine.schema
include C:/OpenLDAP/schema/inetorgperson.schema

pidfile C:/data/slapd/pidfile.pid

database config

database monitor
access to dn.subtree="cn=Monitor" by dn.exact="uid=Admin,dc=my,dc=org" write
access to * by * write

database bdb
include C:/data/pwm/openldap.schema
directory C:/data/slapd/db/bdb
suffix dc=example,dc=it
rootdn cn=root,dc=example,dc=it
rootpw secret
access to * by * manage
index default pres,eq
index cn eq,sub
index sn pres,eq,sub
index objectClass eq
```

With this `slapcat` (cut) output:

```
dn: cn=paul,dc=example,dc=it
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: paul

dn: l=somewhere,dc=example,dc=it
objectClass: top
objectClass: locality
l: somewhere

dn: cn=john,l=somewhere,dc=example,dc=it
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: john
structuralObjectClass: organizationalRole

dn: ou=users,dc=example,dc=it
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: users
structuralObjectClass: organizationalUnit

dn: cn=charles,ou=users,dc=example,dc=it
objectClass: person
objectClass: pwmUser
cn: charles
sn: charles
userPassword:: bWFyY28y
structuralObjectClass: person
```

Why does this return results (actually the "charles" entry):

```
ldapsearch -W -D cn=root,dc=example,dc=it -b "ou=users,dc=example,dc=it"
```

while this gives "no such object"?

```
ldapsearch -W -D cn=root,dc=example,dc=it -b "dc=example,dc=it"
```

I would think that the latter is the most general version of a search, where I'm asking for everything under that suffix.

Comment: It is [**Directory** information tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_information_tree).

Comment: @EJP Uh, thank you for the correction :-)